# Brew with osx 10.11

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I have a lot of stuff installed via brew and there were several compatibility issues with installing programs on OS X 10.10. Now, it is possible to upgrade to 10.11 and I am wondering if it is safe. I mean, is it possible that some programs (`valgrind` for example) become unavailable after upgrading or I am confused and nothing can go wrong?

Comment: Nothing went wrong for me, except the `/usr/local` permission

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t have issues upgrading to OS X 10.11. The only thing new is the “System Integrity Protection” feature (SIP), for which you need to `chown` `/usr/local` to your user after the upgrade.

Homebrew has [a doc](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md) describing how it works. Upgrade your system then run `brew doctor`. If it complains about permission issues run the following:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```